# Adding MySQL and PostgreSQL connectors to Apache Spark environment

Tags: apache-spark, classpath, mysql-connector

In my program I need both MySQL and PostgreSQL connectors. 
I have downloaded both connectors and I can run them one by one; both when I tried to run both connectors I failed.

I run only MySQL connector with this command:

```
./spark-submit --driver-class-path /home/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar --class learner.run.package --master local[8] --executor-memory 8G  /home/project_2.10-1.0.jar
```

And when I wanted to add PostgreSQL connector to my classpath I rearranged my command with `--jars` option:

```
./spark-submit --master local[8] --executor-memory 8G --class learner.run.package --driver-class-path --jars  /home/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar /home/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar /home/merve/Desktop/v1/target/scala-2.10/project_2.10-1.0.jar
```

But it gave me this error :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: learner.run.package
```

I also tried to adding these connectors to spark class path by adding the following line to spark-env.sh :

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH= /home/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar
```

But it could not find MySQL connector.

And finally I tried `.setJars()` option, but it did not work too.

How can I run spark-submit with these 2 connectors or how can I add these connectors to class-path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems:

- `--driver-class-path` should be separated with punctuation marks (`:`)
- `--jars` should be separated with commas (`,`)
- both should passed separately (you cannot do `--driver-class-path  --jars some-path`).

```
spark-submit --driver-class-path some-path:another-path \
             --jars some-path,another-path
             ...
```